# override func in class swift

Tags: swift, class, func

I am quite new to swift and I have a question regarding the definition of functions in a class.
I want to generate several items and give each of them a special function so I can run them by itemxy.useitem()

```
class item {
   var name = "test"
   func useitem(){
   print("test")
   }
}

let staff = item()

staff.name = "Staff"

staff.useitem() // prints: test

*override staff.useitem() = {print("this is a staff")}*

staff.useitem() // prints: this is a staff
```

how can I align a new function to my item staff?

Comment: Oh what I didn't mention is that I wanted to use an Array of the following kind: "var itemarray = [item]()" to store all my items, thats why the inheritance system would be not a very good approach. But I used it anyway now and defined it as [AnyItem]. Not the best solution as i think, but maybe the programming languages are still kind of limited. ;)

Answer (score 2):

These are not entirely swift related and are more general programming, you wont get your answers to such problems here. You should read up on basic programming principles before you tackle things further.

Having said that your problem is easily solved with Inheritance or Protocols.

### Inheritance

```
class Item {

  var name: String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

  func use() {
    print("using a \(name)")
  }

}

class Hat: Item {

  override func use() {
    print("I put on a \(name)")
  }

}

class Pen: Item {

  init() {
    super.init(name: "Pen")
  }

}

let pen = Pen()
pen.use()

let hat = Hat(name: "Beanie")
hat.use()
```

---

### Protocol

```
protocol Item {

  var name: String { get set }
  func use()

}

extension Item {

  func use() {
    print("using a \(name)")
  }

}

struct Pen: Item {
  var name: String

  init() {
    self.name = "Pen"
  }

}

struct Hat: Item {

  var name: String

  func use() {
    print("I put on a \(name)")
  }

}

let pen = Pen()
pen.use()

let hat = Hat(name: "Beanie")
hat.use()
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the Swift manual. The problem is that it generates a new class. So if I have an array of Items, I will not be able to add a object of a type Pen there, right?   

    var itemarray = [Item]()
    itemarray.append(Pen)     // ERROR

so i thought there might be a trick.